# How do you extend SlickGrid defaults?

Tags: slickgrid

I'd like to extend the defaults for SlickGrid but can't find a way to do it.  It looks like the defaults are in a private method.  Has anyone has success doing this?  Is there a different way of setting defaults for SlickGrid that I'm missing?

**UPDATE:** After thinking about it some more, I realized that I could set my own options object and just use that globally.  If I need to change some options or add more, then I can just extend that object before passing it in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whatever options you pass to Slick.Grid in the constructor are used to extend the defaults.
You should not need to change the defaults.

Comment: I'd like to extend the defaults so whenever I new up a grid, it uses my defaults without having to specify them every time...I guess I could create an object with my standard options in it and then just use that each time.  Then I can extend MY options if needed.  I think I just answered my own question.